# Data Format Conversion Python

Tags: python, ajax, data-conversion

I have data in the following format;

```
(('option1', 'option1'),
('option2', 'option2'),
('option3', 'option3'))
```

And require it to be organized like this;

```
[{
    "option1": "option1"
}, {
    "option2": "option2"
}, {
    "option3": "option3"
}]
```

How would I go about this is python? It's to use in some data recieved by JQuery.

Comment: Really? Are you *sure* that's the format you want: a list of dictionaries each with a single key/value pair? Do you not maybe want a single dictionary?

Comment: In which case it's just `dict(your_tuple_of_tuples)`.

Comment: when i define a variable var data = {
    "options": [{
        "foo": "Foo"
    }, {
        "bar": "Bar"
    }, {
        "foobar": "FooBar"
    }]
} in my function the select box populates as it should so just trying to replicate that. What would you say it should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[dict([opt]) for opt in inputlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = (('option1', 'option1'), ('option2', 'option2'), ('option3', 'option3'))
>>> [dict([opt]) for opt in inputlist]
[{'option1': 'option1'}, {'option2': 'option2'}, {'option3': 'option3'}]
```

If all your `option` keys are *unique*, however, you'd be far better of creating just *one* dictionary from these tuples:

```
>>> dict(inputlist)
{'option2': 'option2', 'option3': 'option3', 'option1': 'option1'}
```

Even if the keys are not unique, it'll much easier to map keys to *lists* or *sets* of associated values when you use one top-level dictionary:

```
result = {}
for key, val in inputlist:
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

produces a `result` dictionary where each key references a *list* of values. If any keys appear more than once in the input list, the associated values are then accumulated. If order doesn't matter you could also use a `set()` (using `result.setdefault(key, set()).add(val)`).